# tabla de horarios de atencion sql

Tags: sql

Debo hacer una tabla con horarios de atención de dentistas. Esta misma la voy a enlazar a la tabla "dentistas" así se vera sus respectivos horarios de atención para cuando un paciente solicite un turno y vea los que están disponibles.
Hasta ahora tengo solo los campos de días (1 Lunes, 2 Martes, etc) , id_ dentista, hora_desde y hora_hasta ¿Qué otros campos son necesarios en esta tabla de horario de atención?

Desde ya, agradezco mucho la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrias que tener en cuenta que el horario puede variar con el tiempo asi que tines que tener en cuenta el dia/mes/año a parte de la hora de inicio i la de fin, el id_dentista i probablemente a que paciente que le pertenece el turno. Los dias de la semana lo puedes hacer pero tiene que ser un campo externo o solo texto

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero tu respuesta parece mas bien un comentario, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) un saludo.